# Angular: calling observable getter function from template

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6`.

I have a data class defining JSON object parameters and used as observable like

**contact-list.component.ts**

```
export class ContactListComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts: Contact;

  constructor(
    private contactService: ContactService   
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getContacts();   
  }

  getContacts(): void {
    this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(
      contacts => {
        this.contacts = contacts;
      }
    );   
  }
}
```

**contact.service.ts**

```
export class ContactService {

  private contactUrl = '/api/contacts/';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  getContacts(): Observable<Contact> {
    const url = 'api_url' + this.contactUrl;

    return this.http.get<Contact>(url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('getContacts', null))
      );
  }
}
```

**contact.model.ts**

```
export class Contact {
  count: number;
  next: boolean;
  previous: boolean;
  results: Array<ContactDetails>;
}

class ContactDetails {
  id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  full_name: string;
  private _gender: string;
  private _avatar: string;

  get gender(): string {
    if (this._gender === 'm') {
      return 'Male';
    } else if (this._gender === 'f') {
      return 'Female';
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }

  get avatar(): string {
    if (this._avatar === null) {
      console.log('null is');
      return '../assets/img/bg5.jpg';
    } else {
      console.log('avatar');
      return this._avatar;
    }
  }
}
```

In **ContactDetails** class of **contact.model.ts** file, There are two functions to `gender()` and `avatar()`.

The response from the server has **m** for **male** and *f* for **female** and **avatar** field is null when there is no avatar.

I want to display **Male** or **Female** as gender avatar default avatar when the avatar is not present.

**contact-list.component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let contact of contacts.results">
    <img src={{ contact.avatar }} />
    <h2> {{ contact.full_name }}<h2>
    <h4> {{ contact.gender }}</h4>        
</div>
```

But `contact.gender` prints the value returned from the server and not the one specified in the `gender()` function.

**How can I modify the content of the response data in template?**

Comment: which result do you obtain?

Comment: like in the case of `gender` according to getter function `gender()` it should return `Male` if gender is `m` but it is giving `m` in the template.

Comment: have you tried to debug into browser to see if that function is executed?

Comment: I tried, that function is not calling.

Answer (score 2):

You must map json response (that in fact is a plain object not `Contact` instance as you would expect) to your mapping class. You can do that using `map` and eg. constructor

```
  getContacts(): Observable<Contact> {
    const url = 'api_url' + this.contactUrl;

    return this.http.get(url)
      .pipe(
        map(data=>new Contact(data));
        catchError(this.handleError('getContacts', null))
      );
  }
```

Obviously you must add `Contact` constructor implementation.

```
export class Contact {
  count: number;
  next: boolean;
  previous: boolean;
  results: Array<ContactDetails>;

 constructor(data:Object){
   ///do the mapping here
 }
}
```

Typed responses are good as long as you are using *interfaces* not *implementations*.
After you add this mapping, it will work as expected.

Comment: Do you mean by `//do the mapping here` that inside constructor, I'll have to assign values to the data members like `count = data.count;`, `next = data.next;`, etc and further have a constructor inside `ContactDetail` class which is called like `results = Array(ContactDetails(data.results))` and there is `constructor` in `ContactDetail` to map data members further?

Comment: Yes. That is because you need actual `Contact` object and not only matching `Object` which you are getting from generic typing. If you would only use interfaces, you would not note the difference, but since you need instance methods, than this is the way to go.